# Internet access by anwsering a question or completing a game

Tags: software-development, internet

I hope this is the right place to ask this question. So basically I need to create a system which gives you wireless internet connection if you answer a question or complete a game for my Bachelors degree. I want to compare similar solutions to this type of problem.

For my little project I will be using MikroTik router.

**My question is**, are there similar systems and what are they called?

Comment: So, you're looking for a program that prompts the user to complete a "challenge" (such as a CAPTCHA, or multiple-choice question) instead of entering a WEP or WPA password? In other words, the program would know the WiFi password, but would only attempt to connect to the network if the user solved the challenge correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I would like to think that similar systems could be implemented in schools, or even kindergardens.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to implement a [Captive Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal), which is commonly used in public Wifi Hotspots. It appears that one would need more hardware than just a router to implement one though.